# Writing a function to decode generic JSON. How do I give an argument for Codable.Protocol?

Tags: json, swift, codable

I'm trying to write my first serious Xcode project, and I don't have that much experience with Swift 5. Therefore I'm not even sure if what have in mind makes enough sense.

The project that I have at hand involves a lot of fetching and decoding of JSON files. There are two or three patterns for the responses. So I thought that I would write a `func` and pass it the response patterns.

I use [`decode<T>(_ type: T.Type, from data: Data): JSONDecoder`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder/2895189-decode) to decode my data. The first argument to this function apparently has type `T.Type`. But it actually should be of type `Codable.Protocol`.

Is there a way that I can get that for a `Codable`?

Here is my function:

```swift
func requestPageContent(forCodable codable: Codable, completion: @escaping (Result<PageContent, Error>) -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
        if let jsonData = try? Data(contentsOf: self) {
            if let requestResults = try? JSONDecoder().decode(type(of: codable).self, from: jsonData) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(.success(requestResults))
                }
            } else {
                print("error: json decoder")
            }
        } else {
            print("error: fetch data")
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean for `requestPageContent` to be generic, like this:

```
func requestPageContent<Content: Codable>(forCodable codable: Content, 
                                          completion: @escaping (Result<Content, Error>) -> Void) {

    ...
    if let requestResults = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Content.self, from: jsonData) {
    ...
```

This says that you're requesting some *specific* content type that is known at compile-time.